# Operator + cannot be applied to operands of type IntPtr and int - .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, intptr

The following code (used for looking up DNS TXT records) works fine in .NET 4, however I have had to downgrade the project to .NET 3.5 for various reasons, and now I am being presented with several errors

```
public String DnsGetTxtRecord(String name) {
  const Int16 DNS_TYPE_TEXT = 0x0010;
  const Int32 DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = 0x00000000;
  const Int32 DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR = 9003;
  const Int32 DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS = 9501;
  var queryResultsSet = IntPtr.Zero;
  try {
    var dnsStatus = DnsQuery(
      name,
      DNS_TYPE_TEXT,
      DNS_QUERY_STANDARD,
      IntPtr.Zero,
      ref queryResultsSet,
      IntPtr.Zero
    );
    if (dnsStatus == DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR || dnsStatus == DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
      return null;
    if (dnsStatus != 0)
      throw new Win32Exception(dnsStatus);
    DnsRecordTxt dnsRecord;
    for (var pointer = queryResultsSet; pointer != IntPtr.Zero; pointer = dnsRecord.pNext) {
      dnsRecord = (DnsRecordTxt) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(DnsRecordTxt));
      if (dnsRecord.wType == DNS_TYPE_TEXT) {
        var lines = new List<String>();
        var stringArrayPointer = pointer
          + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt32();
        for (var i = 0; i < dnsRecord.dwStringCount; ++i) {
          var stringPointer = (IntPtr) Marshal.PtrToStructure(stringArrayPointer, typeof(IntPtr));
          lines.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(stringPointer));
          stringArrayPointer += IntPtr.Size;
        }
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  finally {
    const Int32 DnsFreeRecordList = 1;
    if (queryResultsSet != IntPtr.Zero)
      DnsRecordListFree(queryResultsSet, DnsFreeRecordList);
  }
}

[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 DnsQuery(String lpstrName, Int16 wType, Int32 options, IntPtr pExtra, ref IntPtr ppQueryResultsSet, IntPtr pReserved);

[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll")]
static extern void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, Int32 freeType);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct DnsRecordTxt {
  public IntPtr pNext;
  public String pName;
  public Int16 wType;
  public Int16 wDataLength;
  public Int32 flags;
  public Int32 dwTtl;
  public Int32 dwReserved;
  public Int32 dwStringCount;
  public String pStringArray;
}
```

`var stringArrayPointer = pointer + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt32();` triggers "Operator + cannot be applied to operands IntPtr and int

`return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);` returns "The best overload method has some invalid arguments"

Assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
var stringArrayPointer = pointer + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt32();
```

can be changed to

```
var stringArrayPointer = (IntPtr)((long)pointer + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt32());
```

(in .NET 4.0 they added some basic operations to `IntPtr`, but in .NET 2.0/3.5 you had to cast it to `int`/`long`. Casting to `long` is safer because it's 64bit ready)

This

```
return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

to

```
return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```

(In .NET 4.0 they added a `String.Join` overload that accepted a `IEnumerable<string>` as a parameter. In .NET 2.0/3.5 you had to use the overload that accepts a `string[]`)

Comment: Thanks for this! However, in doing as instructed it has now thrown an error on the line `stringArrayPointer += IntPtr.Size`. The error is the same as the other adding error, so i assume the fix is similar, but I have tried casting various combinations to long and have had no luck.

Comment: @Jim change it to `stringArrayPointer = (IntPtr)((long)stringArrayPointer + IntPtr.Size)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't add to an [`IntPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but you can do this:

```
long address = pointer.ToInt64()
             + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt64();
var stringArrayPointer = (IntPtr)address;
```

*(as @xanatos said in his answer, use [ToInt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint64(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of [ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint32(v=vs.90).aspx) to make it work in x64 as well as x86.)*

---

As for the problem with the [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you need to pass it an array as the second argument:

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```